# Preprocessing MS COCO for getting ground truth mask

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

i want to train my neural network for image segmentation using MS COCO dataset,
although i am not able to figure out how to get the ground truth images using their API.
My output is supposed to be 56*56 image containing ground truth mask on which i am supposed to train.
Can anyone tell me how can i get the segmentation mask for MS COCO Dataset?